# Remove Segment Border on ActionBar in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

really need little help here...maybe some walkthrough or shed some light on how to go bout it..I do have skinning my ActionBar with pure actionscript only that I dont have an idea how to remove segmented border between navigation content,action content and titleDisplay..maybe some visual will describe more details..hope someone will help me otu with this..thaks in advanced

[Remove ActionBar Segment Border](http://www.socalledapps.com/img/actionbarimg.jpg)

And here in are my actionscript code attempt

```
package skins{

import mx.core.DPIClassification;
import spark.skins.mobile.ActionBarSkin;


public class ActionBarCusSkin extends ActionBarSkin{




    public function ActionBarCusSkin(){
        super();


        borderClass = null;

    }

    override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        var chromeColor:uint = getStyle("chromeColor");

        var backgroundAlphaValue:Number = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");



        // border size is twice as big on 320

        var borderSize:int = 1;

        if (applicationDPI == DPIClassification.DPI_320)

            borderSize = 2;



        graphics.beginFill(chromeColor, backgroundAlphaValue);

        graphics.drawRect(0, borderSize, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight - (borderSize * 2));

        graphics.endFill();
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The border that you want to remove from Actionbar,
belongs to the Button that appears inside the actionGroup(actionContent) or the navigationGroup(navigationContent). It is controlled by 2 skins upBorderSkin and downBorderSkin ( these are 2 fxg files inside the package spark.skins.assets.mobile) .
What i did in my case to remove it , is that I copied the source from the upBorderSkin (spark.skins.assets.mobile.TransparentNavigation_up.fxg and I created a file BorderLessNavigationButtonSkin in a package assets.mobile.BorderLessNavigationButtonSkin.
The code for the fxg is the following ( there is a Rect separator dark that show the vertical border, i just set the alpha attribute to 0 )

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Graphic version="2.0" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008"
    scaleGridTop="1" scaleGridBottom="64" scaleGridLeft="1" scaleGridRight="79" >

```
<!-- highlight border right -->
<Rect x="79" y="1" width="1" height="63">
    <fill>
        <LinearGradient x="0" scaleX="63" rotation="90">
            <GradientEntry color="#ffffff" ratio="0" alpha=".15"/>
            <GradientEntry color="#ffffff" ratio="1" alpha=".1"/>
        </LinearGradient>
    </fill>
</Rect>

<!-- separator dark -->
<Rect x="80" y="0" width="1" height="65">
    <fill>
        <SolidColor color="#000000" alpha="0.0"/><!--this alpha attribute was set to 0 in order not to appear -->
    </fill>
</Rect>

<!-- highlight border trailing -->
<Rect x="81" y="1" width="1" height="63">
    <fill>
        <LinearGradient x="0" scaleX="63" rotation="90">
            <GradientEntry color="#ffffff" ratio="0" alpha=".15"/>
            <GradientEntry color="#ffffff" ratio="1" alpha=".1"/>
        </LinearGradient>
    </fill>
</Rect>

<!-- invisible fix for scaling -->
<Rect x="0" y="0" width="82" height="65">
    <fill>
        <SolidColor color="#ffffff" alpha="0"/>
    </fill>
</Rect>
```

</Graphic>

then I created a new Button Skin that extends TransparentNavigationButtonSkin with the following code

package skins
{
    import assets.mobile.BorderlessNavigationButtonSkin;

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;

import spark.skins.mobile.TransparentNavigationButtonSkin;

use namespace mx_internal;


public class NavigationButtonSkin extends TransparentNavigationButtonSkin
{
    public function NavigationButtonSkin()
    {
        super();
        upBorderSkin = assets.mobile.BorderlessNavigationButtonSkin;
        downBorderSkin = assets.mobile.BorderlessNavigationButtonSkin;
    }

    override mx_internal function layoutBorder(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        // trailing vertical separator is outside the right bounds of the button
        //setElementSize(border, unscaledWidth + layoutBorderSize, unscaledHeight);
        //setElementPosition(border, 0, 0);

        setElementSize(border, 0, 0 );
        setElementPosition(border, 0, 0);
    }

    override protected function getBorderClassForCurrentState():Class
    {

        if (currentState == "down") 
            return downBorderSkin;
        else
            return upBorderSkin;

    }
}
```

}

and finally a global css style at the application level for button inside the actionGroup or navigationGroup ActionBar

s|ActionBar s|Group#navigationGroup s|Button
        {
            skinClass: ClassReference("skins.NavigationButtonSkin");
        }

I am sure there is a more easy way by setting the upBorderSkin and downBorderSkin  in the css class plus only the fxg file, but in my case i created also a custom ActionBar because i didn't want the background gradient and also the top and bottom borders and it became a little bit more complex